# How to attach source code to dll in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

In one solution, I used some dll file from others. So because there are dll, no source code, I can't debug it.

Now I get the soucre code for the dll, which is a class library. How can I attach this source code to the dll in my solutin so I can debug the dll?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually locate the source code for a loaded .dll from the Modules window in Visual Studio.  For more information, see the VS documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-modules-window

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Updated the link.